# Permalink of a page that has already been deleted

Tags: permalinks, pages

I had a page.. and I by mistake added another one, so the permalink got appended by "-2" at the end. I had to delete one of the pages, so I happened to delete the one without the -2 attached. Now I'm trying to change the slug of the page so that it becomes "pagetitle/" rather than "pagetitle-2" but everytime I edit the permalink it reverts back to "pagetitle-2"   any ideas?

Comment: Remove the page from the trash.

Comment: Hehe yes I just figured that out... I totally forgot the added trash feature. Thanks!

Comment: You should answer the question with this and mark it correct :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I had not deleted the page from trash, so the URL has was still taken up! Once trash was emptied it worked.

Comment: Gentle reminder to mark your own answer as the correct one. :)

Comment: For some reason it didn't let me do that last time! "You cannot do that on your own answer." or something of the sort...